# Android - How to set a drawable resource to the bottom of a vertical progressbar widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I am using the following code to draw a progress bar. I need a small cross at the bottom of my progressbar. How would I do that? Using android:drawableBottom did not work for me for some reason. Here is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/choice_a"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >
        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:progress="0"
                style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Vertical.Yellow"/>
        <com.stuff.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/graphid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/yellow"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                style="@style/sub_header_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a cross that moves with progress I believe that you need to style your progress bar, have a look [here](http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/)

Comment: Not for one that moves with progress. It should stay at the bottom irrespective of the progress

Comment: I assume that you have tried displaying it within an image view and place it right after the progressbar